# Update core via Pantheon

Tags: version-control

I push all my local changes to the Pantheon git repository, then I update core via the pantheon dashboard. Now I pull from the Pantheon repository with `git pull git://github.com/pantheon-systems/drops-7.git master`. I am assuming that both versions are identical now. However, when I run `git status`, I get a message about my branch being ahead of origin/master.

Can somebody explain this to me? How can I get the local and remote repository in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that makes perfect sense - you've merged changes from the core repo, so your working copy is one commit ahead of your site's dev repo on Pantheon. Note that `origin/master` refers to the remote representing *your* repo, not drops-7.git

```
git push
```

to send the changes up to your dev site when you're ready to test, then pull them through the dashboard as normal.

Comment: Thanks Clive, That clears it up. I had assumed that the remote repo and drops-7.git were the same.